# Returning file list inside a directory

Tags: java

This is the piece of code I am working on

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestFileSearch {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
new TestFileSearch();
}
public TestFileSearch() {
File parentPath = new File("D:/Dir/webclient/WebContent/en");
List<String> files = list(parentPath);
for (String file : files) {
System.out.println(file);
}
}

protected List<String> list(File parent) {
return listFiles(parent, parent);
}

protected List<String> listFiles(File parent, File folder) {
List<String> lstFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
if (folder.isDirectory()) {

File[] files = folder.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
for (File file : files) {
if (file.isDirectory()) {
//  lstFiles.addAll(listFiles(parent, file));

File[] filesinsidefolder=file.listFiles();


} else {
String path = file.getPath();
String offset = parent.getPath();

path = path.substring(offset.length());
lstFiles.add(path);
}
}
}
}

return lstFiles;
}
}
```

I am facing a problem here. I am checking if it's a directory and then I want to populate all the files inside a directory like this:

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    File[] filesinsidefolder=file.listFiles();
}
```

However, nothing is getting populated inside `filesinsidefolder` variable, while I know there are about 100+ files inside the folder.

Comment: How do you know `filesinsidefolder` is not populated? You're never using that reference.

Comment: I am using a debugger to check what value is going inside each variable

Comment: At which line do you make the check when using the debugger? Please be aware that you have to execute the line with `listFiles()` call. So you have to be already on the next line, which is outside the `if` block.

Comment: I added a check after                                                          File[] filesinsidefolder=file.listFiles(); like this if(filesinsidefolder !=null)
      {
       
      } its a just a null check so its not going inside that mean nothing is getting populated inside that variable

Answer (score 0):

You will never populate that because you don't have any subfolder in the path you give, anyway that variable `File[] filesinsidefolder=file.listFiles();`
 declared once populated will not be stored and you will loose the subfolder list. Made it global upon main method, check if is not empty and dinamically add\looping to the lstFiles array.

or you can avoid totally the filesinsidefolder variable like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            new a();
            }
    public a() {

    File parentPath = new File("D:/Dir/webclient/WebContent/en");
    List<String> files = list(parentPath);
        for (String file : files) {
        System.out.println(file);
        }
    } 

    protected List<String> list(File parent) {
        return listFiles(parent, parent);
    }

    protected List<String> listFiles(File parent, File folder) {
    List<String> lstFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (folder.isDirectory()) {

                File[] files = folder.listFiles();
                    if (files != null) {
                        for (File file : files) {
                        if (file.isDirectory()) {

                          for (File fileTREE : file.listFiles()) {
                              lstFiles.add(fileTREE.toString());
                          } 

                        } else {
                        String path = file.getPath();
                        String offset = parent.getPath();

                        path = path.substring(offset.length());
                        lstFiles.add(path);
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }

    return lstFiles;
    }
```

hope it helps..

Comment: but listfiles method works when you want to get list of files inside a directory

Comment: yes sure, but with file.isDirectory you're trying to check if every file is subfolder again...so because you have only file in the first path you give it will never satisfy that condition and filesinsidefolder will remain empty.